# Will the old version of Airport Utility still be usable if I upgrade to 6.0?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac, time-capsule, airport

I would like to know if, once I upgrade Airport Utility to version 6.0, the old version I had previously will disappear, and I want to know if I can use both of them (old and new) on the same Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the old version will be removed when you download the new one.

Yes, you can [download the old version](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1482/en_US/AirPortUtility56.dmg) and use both, side by side (according to [this TUAW article](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/01/31/in-pictures-airport-utility-6-0s-missing-features/)).